# issues concurrent queue in GCD in swift 3

Tags: swift3, grand-central-dispatch

i have an problem with GCD in swift 3 
i create the concurrent queue and i pass function in this queue this function call another function
i need to print the elapsed time for each call 
but i think the implementation is cut within the concurrent queue the following my code :

```
// peform task with the concurrent queue
class DoCalculations{
    func doCalc() {
        let x = 100
        let y = x * x
        _ = y / x

    }

    func performCalculation(itretion:Int,tag:String) {
        let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

        for _ in 0..<itretion {
            self.doCalc()
        }

        let end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

        print("tag :\(tag) : \(end - start)")

    }
}


let calc = DoCalculations()

let cQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myCompany", attributes: .concurrent)

cQueue.async {
    calc.performCalculation(itretion: 1000000, tag: "sync1")
}
cQueue.async {
    calc.performCalculation(itretion: 1000, tag: "sync2")
}

cQueue.async {
    calc.performCalculation(itretion: 100000, tag: "sync3")
}
```

// the print function is not Excuted 
please can solve this issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this on a playground, you want to indicate that execution should continue "after the end of the playground’s top-level code is reached." You do this with `needsIndefiniteExecution`:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

As the documentation for `needsIndefiniteExecution` says:

> A Boolean value that indicates whether indefinite execution is enabled.
>   By default, all top-level code is executed, and then execution is terminated. When working with asynchronous code, enable indefinite execution to allow execution to continue after the end of the playground’s top-level code is reached. This, in turn, gives threads and callbacks time to execute.
>
> Editing the playground automatically stops execution, even when indefinite execution is enabled.
>
> Set `needsIndefiniteExecution` to `true` to continue execution after the end of top-level code. Set it to `false` to stop execution at that point.
>   The default value is `false`. It is set to true when `liveView` is set to a non-`nil` value.

Comment: thank you very much but please when i finish the execution or auto is finish because the loop take long time to execute it

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you want to happen when execution finishes? But, yes, this may take a long time, depending upon your hardware configuration.

Comment: i mean if i Execute the above code the loop is still counting long time and the numbers is increase until to reach for 1000000 this is normal or have problem with my code? thank you

Comment: I really don't get what you're saying. You called the function, telling it to perform 1,000,000 iterations asynchronously. And then you told it to also perform 1,000 iterations asynchronously, concurrently with respect to the first loop. And then you told it to do 100,000 iterations, again concurrently with respect to those other two loops. So, yes, you'd expect it to probably finish the 1,000 iterations loop first, then 100,000 iterations loop, and then the 1,000,000 iterations loop (though you're not guaranteed the order as it's dependent upon the device). So what precisely is your question?

Comment: thank you very much now i know the 1000000 iteration it take time more than 100000

Answer (score 0):

**Example of concurrent queue using gcd**

```
    func callGCDWithConcurrentQueue(){
        let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Dmoe",qos:.utility,attributes: .concurrent)
    
        dispatchQueue.async{ // Task 1
            for i in 0...10{
                print(i)
            }
        }
        dispatchQueue.async{ //Task 2
            for i in 10...20{
                print(i)
            }
        }
    }

    callGCDWithConcurrentQueue()  > // Calling Method
```

**// OutPut
/*
0
10
1
2
3
4
11
5
6
7
8
9
10
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
*/**